# Building TensorFlow in h2o without CUDA

Tags: r, tensorflow, gpu, h2o

I have built model with TensorFlow backend on machine with GPU. 
Now i want to use this model on production machine which doesn't have GPU.
I cannot use this model without installed TensorFlow backend but I also cannot install TensorFlow backend on machine without GPU.

Is there any option to built TensorFlow backend for H2O without GPU support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I also cannot install TensorFlow backend on machine without GPU

Do you mean you tried and got errors?

> Is there any option to built TensorFlow backend for H2O without GPU support?

Yes but depending on your machine it might be easy or a bit hacky. If you're running on a MacOS system then it should work out of the box, just [follow our instruction](https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater#diy-build-instructions).

If you are on a Linux based system then you'd have to first change one our scripts, to be exact [this one](https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater/blob/master/thirdparty/tensorflow/cppbuild.sh#L72). You'd have to do two things:

- change `export TF_NEED_CUDA=1` to `export TF_NEED_CUDA=0`
- change `export BUILDFLAGS="--config=cuda --copt=-m64 --linkopt=-m64 --copt=-march=native"` to `export BUILDFLAGS="--copt=-m64 --linkopt=-m64 --copt=-march=native"`

You might also remove `--config=cuda` under `echo "Build pip package"`.

After this you follow the instructions linked above as normal.

This should work, but I haven't tested it myself so should you get errors please raise an issue on DeepWater's Github issue tracker.